# JSON file Size loaded into Snowflake Variant Column

Tags: json, size, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, variant

We have JSON files loaded into Snowflake table (Variant column), the table has 2 column - File name and Variant column (JSON records).

I am able to get the whole table size from information schema, however we are interested in getting the size of each row/record in the table.

Can you please help me if there is any formula/function that can help me to get the row size.

Answer (score 1):

`LEN(expression)` Returns the [length](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/length.html) of an input string or binary value.

You can concatenate columns using [type cast operator](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/cast.html) and get resulted string length.

Like this:

```
len(col1::string||col1::string||colN::string)
```

`len(variant)` also works

Comment: thanks for the reply - If i get the len(variant) as -2647829 is it equivalent to 2647829 Bytes? Thanks

Comment: @gopinathkolanchi Equivalent for binary type only. For strings len returs characters number.  UTF-8 characters are counted as a single character. For binary, the length is the number of bytes. Try converting to binary using len(to_binary(variant)), see https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/to_binary.html